# setting a table component to display using the entire viewport heigth

Tags: jquery, css

I tried using `height: 100vh` and `minHeight:"100vh"` respectively in my component and it doesn't work. It still displays the entire table. I have a max of rows that can be displayed but I want the table to avoid causing a page scrollbar by making the table body the only one that scrolls.

I can achieve this by setting up a definite height and hidden overflow but the definite height is a problem. Not everyone's viewport is the same size and while it is perfect for a few it is either too small for some or too long for others. So, I want this table to read the window height and use that to define when the hidden overflow should start scrolling.

I did find this in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setHeight() {
       windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
       $('.sidebar').css('min-height', windowHeight);
    };
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function() {
       setHeight();
    });
});
```

Problem is, this doesn't seem to work for my table.

I'm adding a [codepen](https://codepen.io/LOTUSMS/pen/jGrbYb) that has a playground for this.

EDIT: For the sake of clarification, here is a visual of my problem

[image]

sidenote: This is actually going to be in a React app, so after it works, I'll still need to get it in ReactJS, but I figured, getting it to work in jQuery will probably be quicker and easier. But if you do happen to have a solution in React, please share.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.dynamicHeight').css('min-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});

// If you don't care about changing the height when the window resizes then you can use the following simplified version instead:

// $(document).ready(function() {
//   windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
//   $('.sidebar').css('min-height', windowHeight);
// });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}

.sidebar {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #f8ca00;
}
.dynamicHeight{
 overflow-x:hidden;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <table class="dynamicHeight">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>    
    </tbody>
    
  </table>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the height of the `.sidebar` instead of the `.dynamicHeight`.  I also changed `min-height` to `height`, as `min-height` will let the height expand past the window if the content is long.  Also, the `innerHeight` returns just a number, you need to add `px` to it.  Some `overflow-y:auto` was used on the `.sidebar`

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.dynamicHeight, .sidebar').css('height', windowHeight + 'px');
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.sidebar {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #f8ca00;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/mathieujonson/pen/EwyVJE)

Comment: I can control the sidebar height without issues. I need the table overflow to never exceed the viewport height. If you notice, in your solution I am still scrolling the sidebar, instead of the table body. Both, the sidebar and the table body must adjust to the window height. Table body is what should scroll. If I make the window taller, the table body and the sidebar adjust accordingly.

Comment: I added an image to my question to clarify. I understand it is a little confusing

Comment: @LuisBrazilva So you don't want the table to scroll at all, even if there's content below?  If that's the case you could change the `overflow-y` to `overflow:hidden` on `.sidebar`, and you'll never get the scroll bar.  You'd be missing the rest of the content though.  Or are you wanting the table to shrink to fit?

Comment: I think you solved it bro. I added bootstrap to the codepen for some css support on resets and the script you modified worked it out! Thanks man!

Comment: @LuisBrazilva Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by setting the `height` or the `max-height` of the `table` to the windows hieght, just remove that padding, see the `code snippet`

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.sidebar').css('max-height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  margin:0px;
}

.sidebar {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: #f8ca00;
  overflow:auto;
}
.dynamicHeight{
 overflow-x:hidden;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sidebar'>
  <table class="dynamicHeight">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr> 
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Body Row</td></tr>    
    </tbody>
    
  </table>  
</div>
```

Comment: I can control the sidebar height without issues. I need the table overflow to never exceed the viewport height. If you notice, in your solution I am still scrolling the sidebar, instead of the table body. Both, the sidebar and the table body must adjust to the window height. Table body is what should scroll. If I make the window taller, the table body and the sidebar adjust accordingly.

Comment: I added an image to my question to clarify. I understand it is a little confusing

Comment: do you want to make the windows to be as the height of the content !?
you want to make the space in the bottom disappear !

Comment: The other way around, the table is dependent of the window size. But yes, the space below the table should be always occupied by the table. RIght now, as you see it in the picture I have the height set at 560px. In larger viewports you can see that space. In shorter viewports, the table expands off screen and you can't see the bottom of the scrollbar.